# Clear views from the Durandal cache

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, durandal

When using option `cacheViews: true`, Durandal caches the views. i.e. leaves in the DOM and just shows/hides them. In one of the use cases in our application, I want to clear them from the DOM so that they are reloaded.
Does anyone know if it is possible, and if yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "There's currently no support directly in Durandal for that." - *Rob Eisenberg*

Reference: [Google Groups discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/durandaljs/YPQCherXu_U).

The workaround is you would have to remove the cached view from the DOM using jQuery, and Durandal will reload it upon its next composition.